# Hard warm start

Tags: starting, chevrolet, truck

I have a 97 Chev K1500 with a 5.7L gas engine. When it is cold it starts right away, when warm it has to crank lots. It runs fine other than this. The fuel injector spider was replaced two years ago. It has a new cap, rotor, wires and plugs. I’m thinking maybe the temp sensor, but is there any other suggestions on what to look for or check?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You might want to check the fuel pressure when it does this to see if it is up to snuff. I believe it should be at ~43.5 psi.

Answer (score 1):

The engine may get flooded.  On a warm engine, left off for 20 minutes, remove the induction tubing, open the throttle body shutter and smell for raw gasoline.  If heavy odor is detected, fuel pressure regulator is leaking internally or fuel injectors are leaky.

The engine may get starved of fuel.  As commented by Paulster2, connect fuel pressure gauge and watch for a drop in pressure over 20 minutes with the engine off.  Now, here's a quick test for low fuel pressure.  When engine is off and warm, turn ignition key "on" but do *not* start engine (you should here the fuel pump for 1-2 seconds in a quiet garage).  Repeat this key cycle 2-3 times, then start engine.  If engine starts immediately, without long cranking, fuel pressure is seeping.  Check the following:  weak fuel pump, leaking fuel lines, leaking fuel injectors, leaking fuel regulator on the return side (remove vacuum line with engine off and watch for fuel drips).  See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HP4ylw2Ow6M) for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  It turned out to be the fuel pressure sensor in the spider.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the resolution to your issue.  I didn't know there was a fuel pressure sensor.